# after insert update query

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `starttrip_trigger` AFTER
> INSERT ON `trip_start`  FOR EACH ROW   SELECT *
>        INTO @device_no
>        FROM meter_data
>        WHERE meter_data.device_no = NEW.device_no;
>        IF @device_no= NEW.device_no
>        THEN
>           UPDATE meter_data SET id=NEW.id,device_no=NEW.device_no,trip_slat=NEW.lat,trip_slng=NEW.lng,trip_stime=NEW.time,odometer=NEW.distance_odometer,trip_id=NEW.trip_id,status=2
>         END IF;
```

i'm getting error near by **'IF @device_no'**. how to clear this error. **ERROR** For if is not valid input at this position.

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: #1109 unknown table 'customer' in field